# Get values inserted for field dynamically

Tags: php, javascript

I would like to insert up to 10 fields dynamically 10 into my form :

```
<form action="" method="post">
    ...
    <div id="dynamicInput">Entry 1
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="myInputs[]">
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Add another text input" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
     ...
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
 </form>
```

JS code :

```
 var counter = 1;
 var limit = 10;

 function addInput(divName) {
     if (counter == limit) {
         alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     } else {
         var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
         newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";
         document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
         counter++;
     }

 }
```

After clicking submit in form ( with post method ) I hope to get values inserted in this field in my php page?

For example I inserted 3 values dynamically using the JS code above, so I hope to get in my php page an array like this :

```
Array(
    [0] => value1, [1] => value2, [2] => value3
)
```

Comment: Why not put that inside `<form>` ?

Comment: It's already inside a form,it's not a solution...

Comment: You want to submit only when limit was reached? And what if user wants to send, for example, 3 or 5 items? (i.e. < 10)?

Comment: @JeanTer What's your problem exactly?

Comment: the problem is to get values of one field dinamically insered between 1 to 10 values,thats mean maybe 4 or 5 or 10 as a user of form hope and finally to get this values in php page like an array to use it easily and save it in database,that's all?

Comment: Doesn't it work? Show us your PHP code that as receiving the POST.

Comment: @Bergi nothing because that im asking for,in my php page I do `<?php var_dump($_POST['myInputs[]']); ?>` and I get `NULL`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial form :

```
<div id="dynamicInput">Entry 1
    <br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]">
</div>
```

and your javascript :

```
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";

document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
```

Give this dynamically generate field the name `name='myInputs[]'>` *myInputs*

Therefore when you receive the forms data back into your PHP code you will receive this in the $_POST array:

```
$_POST['myInputs'][0] = data in the first field
$_POST['myInputs'][1] = data in the second field
$_POST['myInputs'][2] = data in the third field
...
$_POST['myInputs'][9] = data in the tenth field
```

Comment: you almsot send me a good answer,I should just to do this `<?php $_POST['myInputs']; ?>` instead of this `<?php $_POST['myInputs[]']; ?>` and then I get an array with correct values...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do with javascript but by using jquery you can do achieve it easily

please add script jquery.js in your site

HTML

```
<div id="dynamicInput">Entry 1
     <input type="text" name="myInputs[]" class="myInputs" />
     <input type="button" class="add_input" value="Add another text input" />
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var limit = 10;
    $(".add_input").on('click', function(){
        if( $(".myInputs").length == limit ){
            alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + limit + " inputs");
            return false;
        }
        $(".myInputs:last").after("<br>Entry "+ ( $(".myInputs").length + 1 )+" <input type='text' name='myInputs[]'  class='myInputs' />");
    });
});
```

you can also check example at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GvJ8g/2/)